# Redirect to Controller's action method from event handler in nopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using entity updated event of nopCommerce. I want to redirect on my controller's action method.

```
public void HandleEvent(EntityUpdated<GenericAttribute> eventMessage)
{
     //some code for redirect to controller action
}
```

How can i redirect into controller's action method from HandleEvent method.

i want to redirect on Controller's action method from above event handler without using Response.Redirect(url)

Comment: I have already tried that and but it has taken me on the controller's action method, but can not append my partial page

Comment: So, Are you passing partial page from event handler class to the action method?

Comment: Yes, I want to append a partial page after customer save his information from customer info page

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you exactly! but you may convert your partial page to html string and use it in your action method.

Comment: @Div i cannot use like you said because

Comment: in my action method i have return view("partialpage.cshtml") but it is not append page

Comment: Alright, did you get any error?

Comment: yes if i am using Response.Redirect(url) in event then it is redirecting to me on my page but it is give error "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent". and one important thing i have created routing for redirecting url

Comment: It was your last duplicated question, did you check the solutions of that question? if yes  then please all detail to the question.

Comment: ya but now i want to redirect to controller's action method

Comment: i want to just redirect to controller's action method without using Response.Redirect from event handler

Comment: see ->   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931603/how-to-redirect-in-mvc-action-from-orderplaceevent-in-nopcommerce

Comment: @Parita, I can't see clearly what you need from your comments. Are you trying to redirect to some page (like in http redirect)? or add some content to the current page dynamically (like a child action)?. If that's the first one the provided redirect sample would work for you. If that's the second, I think I can help with that too, but please update your question explaining better your scenario.